# Display value of variable in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I want to populate the value of maxbars variable in the width in the percentage format, but for some reasons its not taking its value. Can you please help.

Example: I want to display it as width:10.9% format

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/price">
 Current node:
 <xsl:variable name="maxbars" select="."/>
 <div style="width: 200px; height: 20px;">
 <div style="width: maxbars%; height: 18px; background-color: red"></div>
 </div>
 <br/>
 </xsl:for-each>



<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must indicate that you are using the `maxbars` variable. If you are using it inside of an attribute, you can use XSL-T's curly brace syntax for xPath expressions:

```
<div style="width: {$maxbars}%; height: 18px; background-color: red"></div>
```

**Important:** The braces are placed *around* the expression and you use the `$` inside of the braces.

If you want to insert variables (and other xPath expressions) outside of attributes, then you must use the `<xsl:value-of>` element:

```
<span>Price: <xsl:value-of select="$maxbars"/></span>
```

Comment: The "curly braces" are called an AVT (attribute value template). http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates +1 for a good answer

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** - nd's answer is more elegant - the {} technique is more concise.

As an alternative, you can build up the `div` element manually, in order to substitute the `$maxbars` variable.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/price">
        Current node:
        <xsl:variable name="maxbars" select="."/>
        <div style="width: 200px; height: 20px;">
            <xsl:element name="div">
                <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    <xsl:text>width: </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$maxbars" />
                    <xsl:text>%; height: 18px; background-color: red</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </div>
        <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You can use a literal `<div>` for the inner one, you don't have to use `<xsl:element>` - the `<xsl:attribute>` can add attributes to its containing literal result element.